# Specflow parsing error VS2010

Tags: c#, specflow

is anyone able to tell me what is wrong with my second AND statement in specflow?

perhaps also there's a better way to test this behaviour?

```
Scenario: New Lowest Member changes all existing members
Given the following members are registered to race
| FullName | mMemberID | mGrpID |
| Michael  | 1         | 10     |
| John     | 2         | 22     |
And the following member is added
| FullName | mMemberID | mGrpID |
| Slow     | 3         | 6      |
Then MemberID 2 should have a Handicap of "00:02:30"
And MemberID 3 should have a Handicap of "00:00:00"
```

Comment: Please show your step bindings if the answer given so far doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: What EXACTLY is the eror or problem you are having? Please post more details of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without Vs at my hands. Maybe it's a newline or tab in there somewhere. 
**UPDATED**
I've now tried to copy your scenario into a new .feature file and it works perfectly. So I now think (even more) that there is something hidden messing up your feature. 
The rest of my answer still holds though.

But I would recomend that you dont use implementation names such as mGrpId. Rather use the name of that group and look it up. Remember that you want your end users, testers, analysists etc to be able to read the scenarios.

Change into that and maybe your obscure error goes away as well ;)